# Impact of using recursions in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion

I have written a sample Java class and used recursion for a specific purpose in a method. I have displayed the code below of the particular recursion method (please note that I have mentioned here only the required part from the method).

```
  private String checkForDuplicateCVs(final Integer userId) throws SQLException {

       //
       // Codes to obtain the cvSerialId comes here...
       //

       final Integer cvCount = (Integer) getSqlMapClient().queryForObject("user.getCvCountBySerialId", cvSerialId);

        if (cvCount != 0) {
           checkForDuplicateCVs(userId);
        }
```

It is appreciated if someone could help me to figure out the impact of using recursions in a java program and whether it's a good practice or bad practice. If it's a bad practice then what are the negative impacts.

Comment: Recursion as such is not bad, but you seem to be using it on a method which makes a DB call and that really does not give good vibes, IMHO.

Comment: It usually depends on the depth of the recursion. Implement an iterative algorithm and compare the execution times.

Comment: @RJ - How does a DB call impact recursion??. As far as I know, the stack should not be overencumbered. DB call is costly in terms of time and in recursion we dont get errors due to time constraint, we get errors due to space constraint. Correct me if I am wrong. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is not bad in itself, and in fact it's often the best way to design an algorithm.

That said, in your case I'd say it's poor design. You essentially have a `while` loop that you've implemented with recursion.

There are a few possible problems with this:

- Readability and code maintenance. It's a loop, why obfuscate it?
- Susceptibility to stack overflow. Your recursive call takes the same parameter as the parent, so it's entirely possible that you'll get an infinite loop if the database doesn't change. That's perfectly fine for a `while` loop, but in your case that will eventually reach the stack limit and throw an exception. This would make your use of recursion a bug, one that in my opinion has security implications (Denial-of-Service).
- This doesn't apply to your code, but in general function calls are much more expensive than simple loops. Therefore if you compare the execution times of a `while` loop and a recursive implementation of that `while` loop you'll see a large performance gap. It's possible to optimize this away in some circumstances (namely tail recursion), but not always. (this effect is negligible in your code because the database query is far far more expensive than the function call overhead)

Answer (score -2):

The only dark side of recursion is that you may get a StackOverflowException, if your function will call itself large number of times (you may modify stack size with JVM parameter). Note that the recursion may always be replaced with a simple while loop.

Comment: Recursion may always be replaced by a loop, but it is not always a *simple* loop. It can become very complex.

Comment: Ha-ha, depending on what you mean by _simple_ and _complex_. Every recursive function must have an exit condition which always can be implemented in the infinitive loop as `if(<condition>) break;`

Comment: Recursive functions can have state within their stack frames that is used *after* the recursion returns. Now take a recursive function which calls itself several times within one invocation and uses the results and try to rewrite it to an iterative solution…    Only end-recursion is trivial to rewrite.

Comment: Fair enough. However if there is a couple of invocations of the recursive method, you may always use some advanced data structures to achieve the same using loops. The only thing I tried to say is that recursion can be converted to loop, in case of the huge depth you are forced to do so. Yes, this may require some refactoring.

Comment: That’s the point, “use some advanced data structures” is different to “replace with a simple while loop”.